# logback with play framework

Tags: java, logging, playframework, logback

i want to save my custom log data to mysql database.
i have added appender from log back configuration:

```
 <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.access.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url> jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3308/db</url>
            <user>pidev</user>
            <password>password</password>
        </connectionSource>
        <insertHeaders>true</insertHeaders>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
```

and i also added the access_event and access_event_header to database.

however there is still missing steps to get logs saved to database. any help???

Comment: Are you using a virtual or physical device? Where is the database you are trying to save to, on device or on your local development machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code with following points

1. MySql dependency libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.16"
2. Log tables logging_event, logging_event_property and logging_event_exception with their fields
   http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys,
it turned out all i needed to change is the class name of database from:
`ch.qos.logback.access.db.DBAppender` to `ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender`